# Unable to use curly brackets to assign values to c++ pair

Tags: c++, c++11, clang++

Whenever I use curly brackets to assign values to a pair I get the following error

```
error: expected expression
    p = {0, 0};
```

Here's the code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    pair<int, int> p;
    p = {0, 0};
    return 0;
}
```

I am using a clang compiler that comes with Xcode.

I have no idea why this isn't working as it works fine on ideone

Comment: Clang version? Are you compiling with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: https://godbolt.org/g/zU57bf

Comment: @osaid, Where is your header include for definition of `pair`?

Comment: @SergeGoncharov yeah sorry I forgot to add that

Comment: So does it work with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah it does

Comment: @VittorioRomeo thanks that worked, could someone please provide a link or something through which I can learn why this worked thanks

Comment: That's called [(copy) list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization), and list initialization was added in C++11.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat It's not list initialization of `p`, though it is list initialization of the parameter to `operator=` which gets transferred to `p`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This syntax uses [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), in particular form (10) on that page. Since list initialization was only introduced in C++11, you need to compile with that version. Clang defaults to building with C++98, so you need to specify a later version with the `-std` flag. The minimum one to get list initialization would be `-std=c++11`, but you get more features with `-std=c++14` or `-std=c++1z` (which means the next version of C++, which will almost certainly be C++17, standardized in less than two weeks).

I don’t know what compiler or flags ideone uses when you choose C++, but it apparently supports C++11.

Comment: C++11 is already getting old… it's a good idea to ask for C++14 or even C++17 these days.

Comment: @Potatoswatter You’re right; I was going based on the question tags, but I’ll add that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful